# No Frills Magento Layout: createBlock throws exception "Invalid block type"

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am running Magento 1.7.0.2 (on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS).

I am trying to get a section of Magento code inspired by Alan Storm's No Frills Magento Layout book section 1.8. First of all I think Mage_Core_Template_Block of that section should read Mage_Core_Block_Template.

But more importantly my call to $block = $layout->createBlock('foo_bar/hello') is returning false and throwing an exception in exception.log because it is prefixing foo with Mage thus referencing an object called Mage_Foo_Bar_Block_Hello which does not exist instead of returnin an object of type Foo_Bar_Block_Hello which is what I'm after. Here are the contents of my customization files and the triggering URL:

---

URL triggering the error:

```
http:// localhost/magpractice/helloworld/index/layout/
```

---

/var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

  function layoutAction() {

    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $block = $layout->createBlock('alanstormdotcom_helloworld/hello', 'root');
    var_dump($block);
    echo $block->toHtml();

  }

}

?>
```

---

/var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/Block/Hello.php

```
<?php
class Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block_Hello extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

  public function _construct() {

    $this->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');
    return parent::_construct();

  }

  public function _beforeToHtml() {

    $block_1 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
    $block_1->setText('The first sentence.');
    $this->setChild('the_first', $block_1);

  }

  public function fetchTitle() {
    return 'Hello Fancy World!';
  }

}
?>
```

---

/var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld</module>
          <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
        </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

---

Here are the contents of /var/www/magpractice/var/log :

```
2013-06-11T12:42:56+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block_Hello' in /var/www/magpractice/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('alanstormdotcom...', Array)
#2 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php(38): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('alanstormdotcom...', 'root')
#3 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController->layoutAction()
#4 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('layout')
#5 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/magpractice/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /var/www/magpractice/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Can someone kindly point out where I have gone wrong in my code or state how magento 1.7.0.2 possibly deviates somehow in what is described in the alan storm nofrills magento layout documentation (which apart from this has been an excellent book)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `config.xml` file is incomplete. It should rather look like this :

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
  </modules>
  <!-- Missing blocks and helpers definition here: -->
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block</class>
        </helloworld>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block</class>
        </helloworld>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld</module>
          <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
        </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion by changing config.xml but I still get bool(false) Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php on line 40 ---- line 40 being echo $block->toHtml(); after $block gets set to false.

Comment: What does it give if your replace the line 40 in your controller by this : `$block = $layout->createBlock('helloworld/hello', 'root');` ?

Comment: If I replace alanstormdotcom_helloworld with helloworld as you describe here then it works but I need the two blocks and helpers tags inside <global>...</global> tags for it to work otherwise I get an error. Could you please describe what these do and why they are needed?

Comment: Alan just answered himself to your question, you'll find the right explanations there and the actual solution to make everything work without having to change the example controller

Comment: Yes, I never changed the example controller, but as you pointed out a tweak to the config.xml file was needed, or is Alan's example in Section 1.8 in some way different from mine? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how Alan's example differs from mine in that his example does not require the extra tags in config.xml. Where is the difference?

Comment: I don't have the book so I can't answer you, but in his answer here he also points out the changes to apply to the `config.xml` file, and why it was not working otherwise

Comment: Following your example if I delete the <helpers> section of code it still works. No idea what <helpers> does.

Comment: You'll find a tutorial about helpers here: http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-helper-howto-tutorial-113, or maybe also in Alan's book. This is something that is quite common in Magento modules so this is why I included it in my code, but in your case you indeed don't need them

Answer (score 3):

There's no differences in 1.7.0.2 that wold impact your code — your `config.xml` is missing its `<blocks/>` section.

You're instantiating a block named `alanstormdotcom_helloworld/hello`.  That's a group name of `alanstormdotcom_helloworld`, and a class name of `hello`.

However, your module doesn't have a `blocks` configuration section.  Without this section, Magento doesn't know what PHP class name to use for blocks in the `alanstormdotcom_helloworld` group.  Since it doesn't know, it assumes your block is part of the Mage core and taskes a guess at a name (`Mage_Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block_Hello`).

Look at how the working modules configure their `<blocks/>` section.  That should get you pointed in the right direction.

Without checking my work, your configuration should look something like this

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <!-- ... -->
         <blocks>
            <alanstormdotcom_helloworld>
                <class>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block</class>
            </alanstormdotcom_helloworld>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

If you're still having trouble, try tracing the code back to where Magento creates a class name from the class alias (`alanstormdotcom_helloworld/hello`). Beside solving yoru problem, this is always a good exernice for new Magento programmers.

Comment: Thanks Alan. As per your example $block = $layout->createBlock('alanstormdotcom_helloworld/hello', 'root'); still has to be replaced with $block = $layout->createBlock('helloworld/hello', 'root'); for it to work though. I have already learned a lot from your blog posts and book and I will keep it up though. Thanks a lot (BTW, how do you search the source code, do you use grep or some other more powerful code searching tool to go through all the magento source code and complete the exercise which you mention. I am interested. Thanks.)

Comment: I was missing the enclosing blocks tag in my code sample.  That said, if you're going to stick with Magento it's important you learn to reason about your code, and not blindly copy/paste from the Internet

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check it out.